# Symfony 4 / How to correctly update a twig asset client side with Ajax independently of the current url?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following template code on my homepage `example.com`

```
{% block content %}

  <img id='imgID' src={{ asset(/asset/img.png) }}>

{% endblock %}
```

This loads correctly

Now I navigate to `example.com/foo` by clicking on a link. This page contains an `Ajax` request that returns a new `src` for my `<img>` in the promise:

`$('#imgID').attr('src', '/asset/${newimg}')`

The image updates correctly BUT now if I refresh the browser page by clicking on the browser refresh button I get `404` on my image

Error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://example.com/foo/asset/newimg.png'`

it should be `http://example.com/asset/newimg.png'`

same error if I load the ajax call from anything other than `example.com`

I do not understand why, I am using an absolute path in my Ajax callback. The twig `{{ asset() }}` function is not loading correctly?

What is the correct way of updating a twig asset path with an ajax request from any url without having to use the asset manager server side? Can I somehow specify a true absolute path ?

Do I have to use `composer require symfony/asset` like below and therefore make an Ajax call every time I want to update an asset with Ajax ? Or can I keep it client side ? the entire thing seems over complicated and a complete mess

server code:

```
$package = new Package(new EmptyVersionStrategy());
$img = $package->getUrl('/asset/newimg.png');
```

Comment: shouldn't you always reference the assets with relative path? (e.g. `asset/newimg.png`, note there is no leading `/`)?

Comment: if you mean server side it works without, the server output with `/`